# How to track clicks on Links using GTM

Tags: html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, ads

I have an ads campaign and I don't know from where users came to my website and
How can I know which one of those links users click must

```
www.example.com/twitter

www.example.com/whatsapp

www.example.com/linkdIn

www.example.com/<this will be the source name>
```

I want to know which link users came from using GTM.

All links must open on the landing page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need GTM to track click source. The GA script translates certain query parameters to traffic source dimensions automatically. Those query parameters are called UTM parameters. [Here's](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10917952?hl=en#parameters&zippy=%2Cin-this-article) the documentation on how they're mapped to GA data.

You can use the [url builder tool](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/campaign-url-builder/) to generate a url if you find it difficult to figure out the proper syntax.

Basically, you just generate a link to your landing, embedding there the information about the source and then you post the link on the said source. And you carefully do that for all sources.

Sure, GA also tracks the referrer, but TLS will eraze the query params of the referrer, so it may be much more awkward to use to determine the source, but GA already tries to parse the referrers to determine the source automatically, when no utm params are set. UTMs will override the automatic referrer logic.

Finally, GTM. GTM is powerful. It allows you to do more than that. For example, it's able to override the above described logic and set the source, medium, keyword, even referrer, using JS. Ultimately, mostly because of GTM's ability to deploy custom JS, it is possible to override any field in tracking and add extra fields.